# Cannot Find Symbol (Pointing towards "new" in my initiation of a new class object)?

Tags: java

For a homework assignment I have a "health" or basically a BMI/BMR calculator. When I try to create a new class object using values picked up previously in my Tester class by the scanner it's telling me cannot find symbol. I feel as if it's something obvious but at the same the fact that I'm getting an error doing such a common thing as creating a new object is stumping me.

EDIT: Also wasn't sure how best to paste or point out the line where the error occurs but it's halfway down on the Tester code. I tried to bold it but I didn't wanna break the scroll box.

Actual Error:

```
HowHealthy.java:87: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Healthy(java.lang.String,char,double,double,int)
location: class Healthy
     Healthy healthObj1 = new Healthy(name, genderStatus, weight, height, age);
```

**Class:**

```
public class Healthy
{
 // define attributes
 private String name;
 private char gender;
 private double weight;
 private double height;
 private double weightMetric;
 private double heightMetric;
 private int age;
 private double finalBMR;
 private double finalBMI;
 private double finalTDEE;
 private final double CENTIMETER_CONVERSION = 2.54;
 private final double KILOGRAM_CONVERSION = 0.45359237;


 /* Creates constructor with default values
 */
 public Healthy()
 {
  name = "";
  weight = 0.0;
  height = 0.0;
  age = 0;
 }

 /* Creates constructor with initialized values
 */
 public Healthy(String inName, char inGender, double inWeight, double inHeight, int inAge, int inActLevel)
 {
  name = inName;
  gender = inGender;
  weight = inWeight;
  height = inHeight;
  age = inAge;
 }

} // end class Healthy
```

**Tester**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * A class to test the Healthy Class
 */

public class HowHealthy
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  //Declarations
  String name;
  String gender;
  char genderStatus;
  double weight;
  String weightStatus;
  double height;
  int age;
  int level;

  //Create Health object
  Healthy healthTest = new Healthy();

  //Get and validate info
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  //Enter name
  System.out.print("Person's name: ");
  String nameScan = scan.nextLine();
   if (nameScan.length() > 0)
   {
    name = nameScan;
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Name must include at least one character");
    System.exit(0);
   }
  //Enter gender
  System.out.printf("\n%s, are you male or female (M/F): ", nameScan);
  char genderScan = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
  if ((genderScan == 'M') || (genderScan == 'F'))
  {
   genderStatus = genderScan;
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("ERROR: Gender must be either M or F");
   System.exit(0);
  }
  //Enter weight
  System.out.printf("\n%s's weight (pounds): ", nameScan);
  double weightScan = scan.nextDouble();
   if (weightScan >= 100)
   {
    weight = weightScan;
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Weight must be at least 100 pounds");
    System.exit(0);
   }
  //Enter height
  System.out.printf("\n%s's height (inches): ", nameScan);
  double heightScan = scan.nextDouble();
   if (heightScan >= 60 && heightScan <= 84)
   {
    height = heightScan;
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Height must be between 60 to 84 inches");
    System.exit(0);
   }
  //Enter age
  System.out.printf("\n%s's age (years): ", nameScan);
  int ageScan = scan.nextInt();
   if (ageScan >= 18)
   {
    age = ageScan;
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Must be at least 18 years old");
    System.exit(0);
   }

   //Creating another Health object using values declared from Scanner
**Healthy healthObj1 = new Healthy(name, genderStatus, weight, height, age);**


    System.out.println("\nActivity Level: Use these categories: ");
      System.out.println("\t1 - Sedentary (little or no exercise, desk job)");
      System.out.println("\t2 - Lightly active (little exercise / sports 3-5 days/wk");
      System.out.println("\t3 - Moderately active(moderate exercise / sports 3-5 days/wk)");
      System.out.println("\t4 - Very active (hard exercise / sports 6 -7 day/wk)");
      System.out.println("\t5 - Extra active (hard daily exercise / sports  physical \n\t     job or 2X day training i.e marathon, contest, etc.)");
      System.out.print("\n\nHow active are you? ");
    int levelTemp = scan.nextInt();

    /*Validate the level input */
     if ((levelTemp >= 1) && (levelTemp <= 5))
     {
    level = levelTemp;
   } //if
   else
   {
    System.out.println("Invalid leve - must between 1 to 5");
    System.exit(0);
   } //else    



   System.out.printf("\n\n%s's information\n", name);
   System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f pounds \n", healthObj1.getWeight());
   System.out.printf("Height: %.1f inches \n", healthObj1.getHeight());
   System.out.printf("Age: %d years \n", healthObj1.getAge());

   /*Give the proper syntax for gender */
   if (genderStatus == 'M')
   {
    gender = "Male";

    if(genderStatus =='F')
    {
     gender = "Female";
    }

   }

   System.out.print("These are for a " + gender + ".\n\n");
   System.out.printf("BMR: %.2f pounds\n", healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)); //Pass the weight and height
   System.out.printf("BMI: %.2f inches\n", healthObj1.getBMR(genderStatus)); //Pass the gender
   System.out.printf("TDEE: %.2f years\n", healthObj1.getTDEE(level)); // Pass the level

   /*Give the overall status of the weight */

   if ((healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)< 18.5))
   {
    weightStatus = "Underweight";

   }
   else if((healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)>= 18.5) && (healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)< 25))
   {
    weightStatus = "Normal weight";
   }
   else if((healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)>= 25) && (healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)< 30))
   {
    weightStatus = "Overweight";
   }
   else if((healthObj1.getBMI(weight, height)>= 30))
   {
    weightStatus = "Obese";
   }      

   System.out.println("Your BMI classifies you as " + weightStatus);
 } // end class main
} // end class HowHealthy
                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is expecting 6 arguments and you're only passing 5 (the inActLevel is missing :)).

```
Healthy healthObj1 = new Healthy(name, genderStatus, weight, height, age);
```

While:

```
public Healthy(String inName, char inGender, double inWeight, double inHeight, int inAge, int inActLevel) {...}
```

Edit: And you're missing the getters and setters in your Healthy class but I don't know if it's because you didn't paste everything ^^

Comment: Yeah I tried getting help earlier with this and so a classmate sent me their code to reference but I'm not actually sure why they created a new Healthy object anyway (the healthyObj1)? I'm still trying to calculate the info for my original healthTest object but they made it sound like their code was working. Perhaps not.

If I stick on his path and put in the inActLevel I get all variable might not have been initialized errors. Which makes sense to me. I might have to try it from a different direction again.